# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null, using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` and the important parts in files are... I am wondering since game.js is in a directory below, it cannot find canvas? What should I do?

./index.html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

./javascript/game.js:

```
var Grid = function(width, height) {
        ...
        this.draw = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        if(canvas.getContext) {
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            for(var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for(var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    if(isLive(i, j)) {
                        context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
                    }
                    else {
                        context.fillStyle = "yellowgreen";
                    }
                    context.fillRect(i*15, j*15, 14, 14);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I guess the problem is your js runs before the html is loaded.

If you are using jquery, you can use the document ready function to wrap your code:

```
$(function() {
    var Grid = function(width, height) {
        // codes...
    }
});
```

Or simply put your js after the `<canvas>`.

Comment: I'm still practicing javascript. How would I modify the html/js file to include jquery?

Comment: download jquery [here](http://jquery.com/), then add it to your file `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`. put your codes in `$(function() { });` like what I've written in my answer.

Comment: You can also maintain the script tag at the end of the body element to load after the html has been rendered if it's a simple html page.

Comment: Using jQuery just to initialize a Canvas??? it's clear most of the programmers are stuck in the past when the browsers wars and code were incompatible with each other. I've seen people using jQuery just to throw the most basic elemental primitive "Hello world" alert which frankly speaking is ridiculous.

Answer (score 26):

Put your JavaScript code after your tag `<canvas></canvas>`

Comment: I dont think you can do this in React js files

Comment: @JedLancer in React js you can use UseRef to call that Canvas so you probably wouldn't have the same trouble

Comment: @JedLancer consider  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62247320/7706354 this link if your using  react js

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to include JQuery.
 
In the index.html:
`<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas><script src="javascript/game.js">`
This should work without JQuery...

**Edit: You should put the script tag IN the body tag...**

Answer (score 3):

You should put javascript tag in your html file.
because browser load your webpage according to html flow, you should put your javascript file`<script src="javascript/game.js">`  after the `<canvas>`element tag. otherwise,if you put your javascript in the header of html.Browser load script first but it doesn't find the canvas. So your canvas doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Write code in this manner ...

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script>
var Grid = function(width, height) {
    ...
    this.draw = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if(canvas.getContext) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        for(var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if(isLive(i, j)) {
                    context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
                }
                else {
                    context.fillStyle = "yellowgreen";
                }
                context.fillRect(i*15, j*15, 14, 14);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

First write canvas tag and then write script tag. And write script tag in body.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put`<script src='./javascript/game.js'></script>` after your <canvas>.
Because the browser don't find your javascript file before the canvas

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have your JS file declared inside the `<head>` tag so it keeps it consistent, like standard, then in your JS make sure the canvas initialization is *after* the page is loaded:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

There is no need to use jQuery just to initialize a canvas, it's very evident most of the programmers all around the world use it unnecessarily and the accepted answer is a probe of that.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem like overkill, but if in another case you were trying to load a canvas from js (like I am doing), you could use a setInterval function and an if statement to constantly check if the canvas has loaded.

```
//set up the interval
var thisInterval = setInterval(function{
  //this if statment checks if the id "thisCanvas" is linked to something
  if(document.getElementById("thisCanvas") != null){
    //do what you want


    //clearInterval() will remove the interval if you have given your interval a name.
    clearInterval(thisInterval)
  }
//the 500 means that you will loop through this every 500 milliseconds (1/2 a second)
},500)
```

(In this example the canvas I am trying to load has an id of "thisCanvas")