# An error has occured in 'site url': Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getColomnSet' of undefined with Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium for Python eith the Chrome webdriver to automate the download of a file.

My program works perfectly up to the last step (clicking on the 'download' button) at which point a dialog box is triggered with the text:

*"An error has occured in 'site url': Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getColomnSet' of undefined41"*

What does this error mean and what are the most probable causes?

For reference, here are the last few commands of my program:

```
try:
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'element_1_id')))
finally:
    elem1 = driver.find_element_by_id('element_1_id')
    elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id('element_2_id')
    action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem1).move_to_element(elem2)
    action.perform()
    elem2.click()
```

Comment: Post the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
An error has occured in 'site url': Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getColomnSet' of undefined
```

...implies that your program was unable to read the property **getColomnSet** while trying to *download* the desired file.

Possibly, the main problem is the `js` involved to download the document is invoked before the client renders the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) completely.

The relevant *HTML*, a bit more of your previous *lines of code* and the *error stack trace* would have given us some more idea about what's going wrong.

### Solution

- You can induce some measures to wait till the complete [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) is rendered following the discussion:

  - [**Generic funtion to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)
- A couple of facts:

  - In your code trials I don't see you interacting with the element `(By.ID,'element_1_id')` so possibly you can remove the step of `presence_of_element_located()` for the element `(By.ID,'element_1_id')`.
  - If you still require `presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'element_1_id'))` catch the exception and initiate required steps.
  - As you invoke `move_to_element()` over *elem1* and *elem2* and moving ahead invoke `perform()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [**`element_to_be_clickable(locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)

---

### tl;dr (references)

- [Cannot read property 'getContext' of null, using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291693/cannot-read-property-getcontext-of-null-using-canvas)
- [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined](https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/issues/182)
- [Uncaught Error remote.js](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7351)

Comment: @arassi Upvote this/any answer which is/was useful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - it works on Salesforce Lightning UI screens:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("your ID"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```