# scale html canvas (html / reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas, scaling

I am trying to scale a canvas:

```
class DungeonMap extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.scale(2, 2)
    this.setState({})
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render")
    return (   
      <div className="DungeonMap">             
          <canvas ref="canvas" style={canvasStyle}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The code compiles but the canvas scaling is not applied, i've tried different values for the scaling.

As you can see I also tried putting `this.setState({})` to force a re-render but the canvas is still not scaled.

I am pretty sure that `componentDidMount()` is the right method to use because i have to make sure the scaling is applied after the HTML is loaded: [Cannot read property 'getContext' of null, using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291693/cannot-read-property-getcontext-of-null-using-canvas)

How can i apply the scaling for the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a `width` and `height` attribute on the `<canvas>` element:

```
class DungeonMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() { 
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;

    // to scale the <canvas> element itself
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;

    // to scale the drawings, use the context
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.scale(2, 2);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render")
    return (   
      <div className="DungeonMap">             
        <canvas ref="canvas" style={canvasStyle}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

By the way: I'm not really sure, but shouldn't that `<canvas>` element in your JSX have a closing tag? Or does JSX handle that different? Not using JSX that much myself.

Comment: Will this scale the content of the canvas though?

Comment: No. To scale the content, you'll also need to scale the content via the drawing context. This scales the width/height of the canvas.
For scaling the canvas:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage

For scaling the content:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations

Comment: Wait, so calling ´scale´ does or does not scale the size of the canvas?

Comment: The size of the `<canvas>` and the size of the things drawn onto it are completely different things. Your question says, you want to know how to scale the canvas, that's what my answer is for. If you _don't_ want to scale the `<canvas>` element itself but the graphics it shows, you have to use the `scale` method of the drawing context of the `<canvas>` element. If you want to scale the `<canvas>` element _and_ the stuff it shows, you have to use the code in my answer as well as the `scale` method of the drawing context.

Comment: I edited my answer, so it shows how to scale the `<canvas>` element as well as how to scale the context

Answer (score 0):

try to set a property canvas in a state of component and in the componentDidMount makes setState({width:600,heigth:500})

```
    class DungeonMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state={
        width:200,
        height:300
}
  }
  componentDidMount() { 
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;

    // to scale the <canvas> element itself
    canvas.width = this.state.widht;
    canvas.height = this.state.height;

    // to scale the drawings, use the context
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.scale(2, 2);
  this.setState({widht:1000,height:800})
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render")
    return (   
      <div className="DungeonMap">             
        <canvas ref="canvas" style={canvasStyle}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

this must found