# Loading styles from firebase firestore onto canvas error

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from my firestore database and use that data to create a canvas. My goal is to load a set of images and maps to return several canvases.
I am constantly getting this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`

I have tried using setTimeout()'s to delay the speed to help the data load quicker, but nothing seems to work.

```
var gImgObj;
var gMeme = [];
var gCtx;
var canvas;
function memeDivGet(theId){
      setTimeout(function(){
   db.collection("memeInfo").where("creator", "==", theId)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
             db.collection("memeInfo").doc(doc.id).collection("MIMG")
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                  //alert(doc.data())
                  // alert("here")
                  console.log(doc.data().Coordinates[0].fontSize)
                  gMeme.push(doc.data().BaseIMG)
                  for (var i = 0; i < doc.data().Coordinates.length; i++) {
                    // alert("here" + i)
                    gMeme.push({
                      line: "line",
                      size: doc.data().Coordinates[i].fontSize,
                      align: doc.data().Coordinates[i].align,
                      color: doc.data().Coordinates[i].color, // in color picker, if choosing color from platte notice it stays "solid".
                      fontFamily: doc.data().Coordinates[i].fontStyle,
                      lineWidth: 2, // outline width
                      x: doc.data().Coordinates[i].xPos,
                      y: doc.data().Coordinates[i].yPos,
                      text: doc.data().Text[i]        
                    })
                  }
                  //console.log(doc.data().BaseIMG)
                  initCanvas(doc.data().BaseIMG);
                })
            })
        })
    })
  },1500) 
}
function initCanvas(link) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvasImage');
  gCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  gImgObj = new Image();
   // console.log(link)
    //alert(gMeme[0])
      gImgObj.src = link;
      gImgObj.onload = function () {
          canvas.width = gImgObj.width;
          canvas.height = gImgObj.height;
          drawCanvas();
      };
  //console.log("HERE4")
}

function drawCanvas() {
  //alert(gMeme)
    gCtx.drawImage(gImgObj, 0, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < gMeme.length; i++) {
      if(i > 1){
         drawTxt(gMeme[i]);
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < gMeme.length - 1; i++) {
      drawTxt(gMeme[i + 1]);
    }
    // gMeme.txts.forEach(function (txt) {
    //     drawTxt(txt);
    // });

}

function drawTxt(txt) {
    gCtx.font = txt.size + 'px' + ' ' + txt.fontFamily;
    gCtx.textAlign = txt.align;
    gCtx.fillStyle = txt.color;
    gCtx.fillText(txt.text, txt.x, txt.y);
}
```

What I want to return is a set of canvases with the parameters I want.

My database is set up in this way for this section of the code:

(fooIds meaning a random id set by firebase)

- Collection 'MemeInfo'

  - Document (fooIds)

    - SubCollection 'MIMG'

      - Document 'A'

Inside Each fooId Document, there is a creatorId which helps the computer find who created this meme, I use this to locate the document I am supposed to use for this particular creator's account.

"gMeme" is an array containing information from the database.

An "A Document" has a BaseIMG (the background image), a coordinates array with maps inside (containing the size, color, fontFamily, and other parameters), and a text array with strings inside. There is an image of an "A Document" attached.[image: A Document Example Data]

I understand that this is quite confusing so if you have any questions please ask them in the comments section.

Comment: Is the `canvas` id set to `canvasImage`?

Comment: The `canvasImage` is an id from the HTML, and is set to a canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'getContext' of null, using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291693/cannot-read-property-getcontext-of-null-using-canvas)