# I keep getting the error: TypeError Cannot read property 'getContext' of null and can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to follow a JavaScript game making tutorial, but I get the error: TypeError
Cannot read property 'getContext' of null.  I read on [Cannot read property 'getContext' of null, using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291693/cannot-read-property-getcontext-of-null-using-canvas) that the error is having the script tag before the canvas tag.  I already had my script tag after.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");<br>
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Can we have your whole js code ?

Comment: It seems the canvas code didn't attach: let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I pressed save all it fixed itself.  Of course the answer is this simple.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

canvas is not defined. Define it before calling the getContect method.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
```

Comment: Sorry about that the canvas variable didn't attach to the post.  Just edited it in.

Comment: are you saying, it is already defined in actual code and still resulting in error?

Comment: Yes I already defined it.  Here is full index.js https://imgur.com/a/pJ33wrF